# Finding index of set bit

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

This may be simple but I am new to bit manipulation. I have a string of bits (say Alarm String) and I want to find the index number of all the 1's in it so that I can return a relevant Alarm or error code. For example , if alarm_string = 1011000 then my method should return 3,4 and 6. 
How can I do this using bit manipulation? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) How about a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) if a plain integer + bit twiddling is too hard?

Answer (score 1):

This method should convert your bit field to a list of set bit positions:

```
List<Integer> setBits(int in) {
  final List<Integer> setBits = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; in != 0; i++, in >>= 1)
    if (i & 0 == 1) setBits.add(i);
  return setBits;
}
```

If your input is just a string, then the problem is really trivial.

```
List<Integer> setBits(String in) {
  final List<Integer> setBits = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = in.length()-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
    if (in.charAt(i) == '1') setBits.add(j);
  return setBits;
}
```

Comment: The question says that the input is a string and it mentions that the solution should use bit manipulation.

Comment: OK, so what's your point? Your comment is about as confusing as OP's question.

Comment: My point is simply that your first solution doesn't fit the question because it assumes the input is an int. And, your second solution doesn't fit either because it doesn't use bit manipulation. These two constraints make the solution a bit strange. But, that's what the question seems to ask.

Comment: And what would be your point in the way of any meaningful solution that did fit the question? Arbitrarily throwing in bit manipulation?

Comment: Like I said, I wish the question was less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

[`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) does bit manipulation behind the scenes. First convert the `String` to a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). Then, use [`nextSetBit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextSetBit%28int%29) to find the 1's:

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(inputString.length());

for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); ++i) {
  if (inputString[i] == '1') {
    bs.set(i);
  }
}

List<Integer> ones = new ArrayList<>();

 for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
     ones.add(i);
 }

return ones;
```

Comment: As I said, the implementation of `BitSet` does bit manipulation.

Comment: hello, thanks for these solutions ... I have to use bit manipulation as its faster and i have a really long string :/ , I was trying something with shift operators but didnt work ..will try both the solutions. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

```
String bits = "1011000";

List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = bits.lenght()-1; i>=0; i--){
   if(bits.charAt(i).equalsIgnorCase("1")){
      indices.add(bits.lenght()-i);
   }
}equalsIgnoreCase
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I can easily iterate over string to get the index position however I dont want to do it that way.